# Create MDIForm under Normal Form, and open a MDI Child under MDIForm Error

Tags: delphi, mdi

This is my first topic

In the same application:

I Have a NormalForm (Mainform), that in a Popupmenu call's MDIForm like this:

```
MDIForm:=TMDIForm.Create(nil);
MDIForm.Show;
```

The forms open correctly... Now, in the MDI form i try to create MDIChild with:

```
  fm := TMDIChild.Create(Self);
  fm.FormStyle:=fsMDIChild;
  fm.Show;
```

Retrieve the error: 
Cannot Create Form. No MDI Forms are currently active

Anyone knows how do that?!

Answer (score 4):

You can't mix form styles like that.  An MDI child form expects the main form of the application to be an MDI form. The VCL's code does not look to see if *any* MDI forms are available when the child is created.

Comment: Code to see if any MDI Form are available!? do you know how i do that?

Comment: Have a look at TCustomForm.CreateWindowHandle in Forms.pas.  This is the VCL code that is causing your problem.  MDI is an old technology that most people have gotten away from and trying to force it to work in a way that it wasn't designed is asking for trouble.  One workaround might be to make your MDI form the actual main form but keep it hidden.  Your current main form would be shown at startup and when its popup menu wants to show the MDI form it wouldn't create it as in your example but rather just show it.

Comment: @user1147833 Well that's the point. The VCL code, which you can't change, assumes that the main form, i.e. `Application.MainForm`, is the MDI form. You'll need to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

The VCL does not natively support what you are attempting.  It requires the app's `MainForm` to be set to `FormStyle=fsMDIForm`, and it **only** looks at the MainForm.  Your MainForm is not set up that way.

This is a VCL limitation, not a Windows limitation.  It is possible to work around this and use MDI child forms in other non-MainForm forms, but it requires quite a bit of hacking of the VCL's source code.  See [this example](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23574) and [this QC report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=12006).